# Which Files are required to build and run project in VS 2013 for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created wpf application in vs 2013.
But I want to give it to other person to build and run it.
So I want to remove unnecesary files which are not reguired to build and run project.

Comment: Source control might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

- Delete Bin & Obj Folders
- Delete Un-Referenced classes & projects
- Clean the Solution